# WMV file plays on WP8 emulator - fails to play on device

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, wmv, windows-phone-8-emulator

I've got a url to a WMV file, which I want to play with a `MediaPlayerLauncher` in my app. This works just fine in the emulator, but when I try this on my device, running the exact same code as in the emulator, I get the message "Sorry we cant play this file on your phone". My phone is a HTC 8x. Does anyone know why this may occur?

Answer (score 1):

The video codec support for the emulator doesn't exactly match the device.

Also depending on the exact chipset on the phone the codec in a particular audio or video file may not be supported on any particular device. You can find more information on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff462087%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Ok.. Well I may have forgotten to mention that I have previosuly been able to play these files on my device. The location of the WMV files have been changed, so I changed the URL's in the app accordingly. After that, it just doesnt work on the phone. But that  doesnt make any sense, since the URL's work as I can play them on the emulator. Anyway, thanks for your reply, ill see what I can find on MSDN.

Comment: Also, I just tried debugging on my device, and then I can play the videos! This just doesnt make any sense for me..

Comment: I wish it was, but it's not.

Comment: Uh, looks like the problem solved itself, somehow. Thanks for your replies nonetheless :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

When you attempt to play an AudioTrack from your app and there's no response at all (not even an Exception generated), play something from the phone's Music+Videos app (either a song or a podcast), and then try your app again.

(I'm still debugging this issue with the BackgroundAudioPlayer...I think I may be passing it a filename in ISO storage that hasn't finished downloading.  On which the AudioPlayer is then choking, which I'm then failing to detect and recover from.  I'll post here again on any progress made.)

Comment: Ok, figured out my issue.  If you're also having the above issue with playing tracks AND the workaround I mentioned above fixes it for you, here's some food for thought:

If you use ISO storage to communicate with your AudioPlayerAgent (APA) instance from your UI code, be wary of any static objects defined in that APA instance that may be caching that data.

When you play something from another app, or when you call Abort() from your APA instance, all the static objects in your current APA instance are destroyed and can then reload anew upon the next UserAction.Play.